# UPI payment intent link not opening payment apps

Tags: android-intent, upi

upi intent link not opening not installed app. in absence of the app it will open playstore. if the app not installed (previously it will work like this.)

right not working as i expected.

the link was :  `<a href="bhim://upi/pay?pa=7838304007@cosb&amp;tr=AIRPAY17702040&amp;am=1.00&amp;pn=QWRhbSBJbm5vdmF0aW9ucyBUZXN0&amp;cu=INR&amp;tn=Pay to QWRhbSBJbm5vdmF0aW9ucyBUZXN0&amp;mc=5045&amp;mode=04">bhim</a>`